# Android XML buttons

Tags: android, xml

i am trying to make a calculator for android. I have started using XML to make the buttons and such and then i was going to reference them in java for the math. I am having trouble making them be buttons instead of lines. I understand the weight sum, but i don't even know if that is what i am supposed to be using for this kind of thing. My code is the following: (code has been updated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/total"
    android:textSize="45sp" 
    android:id="@+id/calcDisplay"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"

    />        

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"

     />  

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"

     />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"            
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"

    />        

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"


    />        

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"

    />   

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"


    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"

    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"

    />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/number0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

You will want to replace `fill_parent` with `match_parent`, unless you are targeting API 7 or lower. If it is API 8 or higher use `match_parent`. Also, you will want to add `android:text="My String Here"` to each button otherwise with `wrap_content` they will be nothing more than a line currently since there is nothing to "wrap" around.

Then in java you can do the following in your `onCreate()`:

```
Button number1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number1);
number1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      //Do action stuff!!!
   }
});
```

I would also use lower case in your xml, on occasion uppercase will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want nos. to be displayed as buttons do this->

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/total"
    android:textSize="45sp" 
    android:id="@+id/calcDisplay"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"


    />        

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"


     />        

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"


     />
     </LinearLayout>        

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"


    />        

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"


    />        

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"


    />        
    </LinearLayout>    

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"


    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"

    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Number9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="9"

    />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/number0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"


        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Also for JAVA reference you can do this->

```
Button number1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Number1);
number1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      //What to do when 1st button is clicked
   }
});
```

Comment: Since you copied that java code from my answer it will not work for your xml answer. You might want to look into that.

Comment: My buttons are still in a list going from the top down, i am trying to get them to be like a real calculator so one beside each other. So there is 3 in each row, and then leaving space to putt other buttons. How would i do that?

Comment: I changed my code to how you have it set, but now i just have 4 blank bars where my buttons should be instead of 3 buttons one beside each other, i have updated my code if wouldn't mind taking a look